Pressure field due to line source
The question is rather simple, yet I haven’t managed to find a solution to it. I am looking for an expression that gives the complex pressure (free) sound field generated by an infinite line source. Below is the equation providing the sound field for a point source to make my point clear.
$$ p \left( r, \omega \right) = \frac{\textrm{i} \omega \rho Q}{4 \pi r} e^{-\textrm{i} k r} = \textrm{i} \omega \rho Q \frac{e^{-\textrm{i} k r}}{4 \pi r} = \textrm{i} \omega \rho Q G_{3 \textrm{D}} \!\left( \mathbf{r} | \mathbf{r}^{\prime} \right), \tag{1} \label{1} $$
where $r$ is the distance between the source and any point in $3\textrm{D}$ space, $\textrm{i}$ is the imaginary unit (for which $\textrm{i}^{2} = -1$ is true), $\omega = 2 \pi f$ is the radial frequency with $f$ the temporal frequency, $\rho$ is the density of the medium of propagation and $k = \frac{\omega}{c}$ is the wavenumber with $c$ denoting the speed of propagation. $G_{3 \textrm{D}} \!\left( \mathbf{r} | \mathbf{r}^{\prime} \right) = \frac{e^{-\textrm{i} k r}}{4 \pi r}$ denotes the $3 \textrm{D}$ free field Greens’s function and $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}^{\prime}$ are the position vectors of the source and “observation point” respectively.
Now, I do take for granted that the $2 \textrm{D}$ free field Green’s function for an infinite line source is given by
$$ G_{2 \textrm{D}} \!\left( \mathbf{r} | \mathbf{r}^{\prime} \right) = \frac{- \textrm{i}}{4} H_{0}^{\left( 1 \right)} \left( k r \right), \tag{2} \label{2} $$
where $H_{0}^{\left( 1 \right)} \left( k r \right)$ denotes the zeroth order Hankel function of the first kind. However, this is just Green’s function that provides information only on the propagation characteristics of the radiated pressure field. I haven’t managed to find any equation that provides the frequency dependence of the generated pressure field.

Short Answer: I believe the Green's function provides the information you are looking for.  Simplify multiply the Green's function by the source amplitude for a point source.
Longer Answer:
The equation for the complex amplitude of the acoustic pressure with some source distribution may be written as
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 p + k^2p = -i\omega\rho q(\mathbf{r}), 
\end{equation}
where $i\omega\rho q(\mathbf{r})$ is the mass acceleration per unit volume of the source distribution.  (Note that we are using the $e^{i\omega t}$ time convention.)  Mathematically, this equation may be solved using a Green's function $G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}')$ as
\begin{equation}
p = i\omega\rho \int_\Omega G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}')q(\mathbf{r}')\ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}',
\end{equation}
where $\Omega$ is the domain over which the sources exist.  (Note that different definitions of the Green's function will have minus sign in front, so make sure you are using the proper definition.)  If we are interested in a point source at the origin (or a line source for 2D waves), we let $q(\mathbf{r})=Q\delta(\mathbf{r})$, and obtain
\begin{equation}
p = -i\omega\rho Q G(\mathbf{r},0).
\end{equation}
This equation is accurate for 1D, 2D, and 3D cases; the only difference is the form of the Green's function.  Explicitly, for 2D we may write
\begin{equation}
  p = \frac{i\omega \rho Q}{4}H_0^{(1)}(kr),
\end{equation}
where we have used the Green's function you provided above.  Based on the wording of your question, I will also point out that this equation depends on frequency in $\omega$ and $k$ by definition, and also implicitly on $Q$; the source may have a different amplitude at every frequency.
